# Print number upto decimal places

Tags: javascript

I need to print a number up to two decimal places, in JavaScript code.
Here is my code:

```
var num = 10;
var storeNum = num.toFixed(2);
console.log(storeNum);
typeof(storeNum);
```

when i check **typeof** the number it is string.
and when i use **Number** function to convert back to number, it again removes the decimals.
output:

```
10.00
"string"
```

The other code:

```
var num = 10;
var storeNum = num.toFixed(2);
console.log(storeNum);
console.log(typeof(storeNum));
storeNum=Number(storeNum);
console.log(storeNum);
console.log(typeof(storeNum));
```

output:

```
10.00
string
10
number
```

can anyone suggest me a proper solution for it.
I don't want the output in string format.

Comment: Not really. Numbers don't have formats - you use a format when you convert a number to a string (or parse a string to a number).

Comment: It doesn't matter in numbers `10 == 10.00`, formats belong to strings.

Comment: The format is really just for display/print purposes only.

Comment: yeah u right, I am just trying to avoid conversion of string back to number for some calculation.